# How can I output a helper from erb.js in rails 3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, helper

This is what I have in my erb.js file....but it doesn't work:

```
  1 //Update with a message
  2 $('#follow-update').html("<%= follow_button(@question) %>")
```

follow_button is a helper:

```
20   def follow_button(resource)
 21     
 22     type = resource.class.name
 23     follow_status = current_user.following?(resource)
 24 
 25     verb = "Follow" if follow_status == false
 26     verb = "Unfollow" if follow_status == true
 27 
 28     content_tag(:div, :class => "follow-button") do
 29       link_to "#{verb} this #{type} ", follow_path(:followed_type => type,
 30                                                   :followed_id => resource.id,
 31                                                   :follow_verb => verb), 
 32                                                   :class => "button",
 33                                                   :remote => true
 34     end
 35   end
 36 end
```

The helper stand-alone works fine, but I want it to update my button.  Perhaps there's a way to just update the text without replacing the whole helper?

Comment: hmm...okay I played around with just changing the button text, so far so good...may need to delete this.... :)

Comment: nope, I do need it to redisplay the helper because the logic needs to run again....

Answer (score 4):

Create a partial that holds your contains only your helper.

For example: '/wherever/_follow_button.html.erb'

Inside, call your helper:

```
<%= follow_button(question) %>
```

Next, render it using JS.

```
$('#some-id').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('/wherever/follow_button', :question => @question)) %>");
```

There are ways to make this more efficient but hopefully this helps for now.

Comment: Escaping the value returned, as mentioned above, fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need escape_javascript

```
$('#follow-update').html("<%= raw( escape_javascript( follow_button(@question ))) %>");
```

If this doesn't work, please see show the returned ajax text and the button html

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a helper method from a `js.erb` file unless you explicitly include it as described in [Using a Rails helper method within a javascript asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451517/using-a-rails-helper-method-within-a-javascript-asset) .  For example:

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include ApplicationHelper } %>
```

And you should be careful about escaping your HTML too.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I cannot test right now, but have you paid attention to html safe or javascript escapes?

e.g. try to enclose your `follow_button(@question)`in `raw()` or `escape_javascript()`?