# How can I run SOME initializers when doing a Rails assets:precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

## Background

I have an app that I recently updated to Rails 3.2.1 (from Rails 3.0.x) and have refactored the JS and CSS assets to make use of the new asset pipeline.  The app is hosted on Heroku with the Celadon Cedar stack.

#### App Config

I keep application specific configuration in a YAML file called app_config.yml and load it into a global APP_CONFIG variable using an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/load_app_config.rb

app_config_contents = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/app_config.yml")
app_config_contents["default"] ||= {}
APP_CONFIG = app_config_contents["default"].merge(
                       app_config_contents[Rails.env] || {} ).symbolize_keys
```

#### Asset Compilation on Heroku

Heroku has support for the Rails asset pipeline built into the Cedar stack.  When you push an app to Heroku it automatically calls `rake assets:precompile` on the server as a step in the deploy process.  However it does this in a sandboxed environment without database access or normal ENV vars.

If the application is allowed to initialize normally during asset precompilation an error is thrown trying to connect to the database.  This is easily solved by adding the following to the application.rb file:

```
    # Do not load entire app when precompiling assets
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

## My Problem

When `initialize_on_precompile = false` is set, none of the initializers in `config/initializers/*` are run.  The problem I am running into is that I need the APP_CONFIG variable to be available during asset precompilation.

How can I get `load_app_config.rb` to be loaded during asset compilation without initializing the entire app?  Can I do something with the `group` parameter passed to Rails::Application.initialize! ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Rails lets you register initializers only in certain groups, but you need to use the Railtie API:

```
# in config/application.rb

module AssetsInitializers
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "assets_initializers.initialize_rails",
                :group => :assets do |app|
      require "#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/load_config.rb"
    end
  end
end
```

You don't need to check if AppConfig is defined since this will only run in the assets group.

And you can (and should) continue to use `initialize_on_precompile = false`.  The load_config.rb initializer will be run when initializing the app (since it's in `config/initializers`) *and* when pre-compiling without initializing (because of the above code).

Comment: This is the cleanest, most direct way to solve this problem by far.  Why has noone else upvoted it?  It works...

Comment: @gabe-kopley, while @alg's solution has been working for me for some time, this is most definitely cleaner and I'd like to switch it to the accepted answer.  Just to be clear, when setting up the AssetInitializers module this way should I set `initialize_on_precompile = true` or `initialize_on_precompile = false`? In other words will this approach cause the `load_config.rb` initializer to run *regardless* of the `initialize_on_precompile` setting, or limit the total set of initializers that run when `initialize_on_precompile = true`?

Comment: After adding the above Railtie in application.rb, and running  RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace.  Still I see the same error. I am not able to see load_config.rb getting loaded in the back trace. Any other suggestion would be really helpful  Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems this solution is obsolete in Rails4 and 5 - any solution for newer versions of Rails?

Answer (score 7):

Definitely check out **asset_sync** on github. Or our Heroku dev centre article on [Using a CDN asset Host with Rails 3.1 on Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31).

The issues with **environment variables** have recently been solved by a Heroku labs plugin, that makes your application's `heroku config` variables accessible during compilation time. To enable this, read about the [user_env_compile](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) plugin.

Also. There is quite a big performance improvement in using **asset_sync** vs letting your application lazily compile assets in production or serving them precompiled directly off your app servers. However I would say that. I wrote it.

- With asset_sync and S3 you can precompile assets meaning all the assets are there ready to be served on the asset host / CDN immediately
- You can only require the **:assets** bundle in application.rb on precompile, saving memory in production
- Your app servers are NEVER hit for asset requests. You can spend expensive compute time on, you know. Computing.
- Best practice HTTP cache headers are all set by default
- You can enable automatic gzip compression with one extra config

Comment: I believe the Heroku labs user_env_compile plugin combined with setting `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true` again should solve my problem but since the solution in the accepted answer is already in place I haven't tried it yet.  Your **asset_sync** gem doesn't really help solve the problem in this question, but we do use it to push assets to S3 to seed CloudFront and it's great.

Comment: It seems this solution is obsolete in Rails4 and 5 - any solution for newer versions of Rails?

Comment: In Rails 4.2 it seems like the initializers get loaded anyway. I trying loading my constant as part of my compile and got a warning message that it was defined elsewhere (my initializer). Where my problem came in was caching. I deleted my tmp/cache folder and script compiled correctly. If you're having problems I would try that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with. In the assets that need app configuration, I place this line at the very beginning:

```
<% require "#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/load_config.rb" unless defined?(AppConfig) %>
```

... and add `.erb` to the file name, so that `video_player.js.coffee` becomes `video_player.js.coffee.erb`. Then I can safely use `AppConfig['somekey']` afterwards.

During the asset pre-compilation, it loads app config despite the `initialize_on_precompile` set to `false`, and does it only once (which avoids constant redefinition issues).

Yes, it's a kludge, but many times nicer than embedding configs in asset files.

Comment: Thanks @Alg, I've actually been using a variation of the same strategy.  

Instead of adding the `require` line to _each_ asset that makes use of the load_config initializer I just created a **single dummy asset** (load_app_config.js.erb) that contains _only_ the `require` line.  

Then I just do an asset require for that file at the top of each of my asset manifest files.  As long as the dummy asset is loaded before the assets making use of the initializer everything works fine.

I was hoping there was a less hacky solution but since you're answer is so close to what I used I'll accept. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

For Heroku I am running the Asset Sync gem to store my files on a CDN to avoid hitting Heroku for static images.  It works nicely.  I also have initialize on precompile false, but the Asset Sync runs it's own initializer so you could put your code in that.  https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync

Comment: Thanks @Amala, looks interesting.  In the past I have just let CloudFront load assets directly from my app server.  It looks like asset_sync pushes the compiled assets to S3 and then I assume you just point your CDN at your S3 bucket.  Have you noticed a big improvement vs. letting the CDN load up it's cache directly from your app server?

Comment: I have not setup cloudfront, i am simply using S3.  The application I am working on is internal so I just haven't taken the extra step for cloudfront.  I should I guess ;-)

Comment: If you're already syncing assets to S3 it's dead easy to add CloudFront. We're now using asset_sync as you described to push to S3, and then seeding CloudFront from there. Thx a lot.

Comment: Yeah i went online and checked it out after that, it was very easy, is actually slightly cheaper for large scale.

Answer (score 0):

Although your intializer is not run when the assets are precompiling, you should still find that they run as Rails boors up as normal, however, this will be on the first hit to the application rather than at the deploy step.

I'm not entirely sure what the issue you're having is, but if you follow the Rails conventions the deploy will work as expected.

Comment: You are correct that the initializers work when the web server boots up but you're missing the point, I need access to those config variables **DURING** asset precompilation.  As I mentioned in my question the Rails convention in this circumstance is to set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true`, however this breaks asset compilation on Heroku because the dyno that does the compilation is not granted access to the database.  The challenge is running the initializer I want without initializing anything that connects to a DB. @Alg offered a viable solution above.