# How to run Rails server without initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, initialization, rake, task

I have set up a bunch of initialising tasks that call various APIs and save them to constants for access in my controller (this may well be bad form, but I don't need them saved to the database for now).

Is there any way to run

```
rails s
```

without initializers, such as a setting up a specific environment that ignores them, or would this be bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

There are option to group initializers and then run only certains of them (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235292/how-can-i-run-some-initializers-when-doing-a-rails-assetsprecompile)), but if this is a temporary situation, you have a lot of options:

- Just comment out the ones you don't need (if this is just a test on your machine)
- Add a if `Rails.env.development?` clause to those you don't want to run locally (if this is for all development environments)