# Rails ERB route helper _path method not found in JSX asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, reactjs, helper

I'm compiling some JSX assets as part of my Rails 4 app with ReactJS (using the [gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails)) and I'm unable to use route helpers despite including them as specified in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451517/using-a-rails-helper-method-within-a-javascript-asset).

```
/railsapp/app/assets/javascripts/components/GigSearchForm.js.jsx.erb:47:in `block in singleton class': undefined local variable or method `gigs_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f80bb0b1df8>:0x007f80bb1528e8> (NameError)
```

As you can see, the asset is being transformed from ERB to JSX to JS, and while processing the ERB the route helper `gigs_path` cannot be found. I've already tried implementing solutions such as including an initializer like so:

```
Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval do
  include ActionView::Helpers
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
Sprockets::Context.send :include, Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
Sprockets::Context.send :include, ActionView::Helpers
```

And at the top of the JSX file including the line: `<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers } %>`

Nonetheless, I keep getting a similar error that gigs_path is undefined in some manner.

Comment: Have you tried using the [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes) gem? Useful to whitelist some urls to be used in your JS code.