# Rails how do I pass a rails variable to CKEditor config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

My scenario is that, some user who has the `font_user` role can use font, but others can't.

In `ckeditor/config.js`, I can't get any variable from Rails. How do I achieve this?

I have tried something like this:

1. Modify `config.js` to `config.js.erb`.
2. Add the following code.

   ```
   <% current_user.has_role?(font_user) %>
     XXXXX
   <% else %>
     XXXX
   <% end %>
   ```

   and I added the following method in `application_controller.rb`:

   ```
   helper_method :current_user
   ```

   But it seems `config.js.erb` can't get the `current_user` variable.

Comment: Please have a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451517/using-a-rails-helper-method-within-a-javascript-asset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because asset JavaScript is compiled ones. Not each time a view is rendered. You should make use of unobstructive JavaScript. For example:

View example:

```
<div class="ckeditor" data-ckeditor-font="<%= current_user.has_role?(font_user) %>"></div>
```

---

**Alternatively (not checked):**

You could also use the [*#content_tag*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) for this, although you have to check how to exactly pass along the data attributes. If I'm not mistaken:

```
<% data = {
  'ckeditor-font': current_user.has_role?(font_user),
  # other data...
} %>

<%= content_tag :div, class: 'ckeditor', data: data %>
```

But I currently don't have the setup to test the above code. So you'll have to check it yourself.

---

Than in your asset JavaScript (CoffeeScript):

```
initCkeditor = (element) ->
  fontUser = element.dataset.ckeditorFont == 'true'

  # further CKEditor initialization code...


document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:load', ->
  document
    .querySelectorAll '.ckeditor'
    .forEach initCkeditor
```

If you don't set the `data-ckeditor-font` attribute the code still works. Since `element.dataset.ckeditorFont` would return `undefined`, and `undefined == 'true'` is still `false`. (Keep in mind that the CoffeeScript `==` equals JavaScript `===`.)

See:

- [Working with JavaScript in Rails: Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript)
- [The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for more info about the asset pipeline.
- [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for more info about data attributes.

Comment: My question is that I can't get the current_user variable from the backend.

Comment: You can pass it along the same way. Just create an attribute `data-ckeditor-current-user-id`. The question is what are you going to do with the `id` when you have it there? The better option is to set CKEditor options in the view by passing along via the data attributes. Thus having something like `<div class="ckeditor" data-ckeditor-font="<%= current_user.has_role?(font_user) %>"></div>` in your view.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean now. I will try this way.